# how to get particular cl_id order detail and ammount

Tags: sql, sql-server

in thisquery i want to display particular cl_id order detail and ammount

```
select  
    distinct dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,
    count(dbo.IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId) as Orders,
    OverallTotal = (select 
                        sum(in_total) 
                    from IN_Invoices 
                    where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=1 and                          
                          datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014)  
from IN_Invoices
inner join CLOI_ClientOrderItems on 
    IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id='100000_Pri' 
group by cl_id
```

Comment: Added the sql-server tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: What do you want to do?  Sample data and desired results are very useful.  I simply do not understand:  "i want to display particular cl_id order detail and ammount".

Comment: i have 3 tables 
1.CL_Clients 
2.CLOI_ClientOrderItems 3.IN_Invoices from tat i want result.....how can i show the fields

Comment: Let me repeat:  sample data and desired results.  You can show the values in the fields using a SQL query.  Which one is the question.

Comment: cl_id         orders overalltotoal 
100000pro       5       39949
100001pro       64      39949